# Python Tkinter - Frame that can be resized with mouse stops working when I put widgets in it

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI with a panel on the side that the user can resize with the mouse.
To do so, I created a specific object (ResizableFrame) that inherits from tk.Frame and has some extra function to adjust its size dragging one edge with the mouse.

It seems working very well, however it stops working whenever I put any other widget in it. In this specific case I am placing a notebook inside it.

For some reasons, when I try to resize the frame, the frame just flickers like if the notebook - or whatever other widget - is forcing it back to its original size even though I set the notebook to expand.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Why is it doing that? What am I missing?
2. I had to add some padding on the right of the notebook to actually interact with the edge of the ResizableFrame and resize it. If I remove the padding I cannot "grab" the edge. Is there a more elegant way to do that beside adding some padding?

P.S. If you copy and paste the code below you should be able to run my small GUI without many issues. I marked the lines of code that you should comment to remove the notebook and verify that the ResizableFrame works well.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class ResizableFrame(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Resize mode
        self.NONE = 0
        self.HORIZONTAL = 1
        self.VERTICAL = 2

        self.resizeMode = self.NONE
        self.isDragBandHeld = True
        
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartResize)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopResize)
        self.bind("<Motion>", self.MonitorCursorPosition)

        self.cursor = ''
        self.dragBandWidth = 10


    def StartResize(self, event):
        '''Set the resize mode if the left button of the mouse is clicked close to the right or bottom edge of the frame.'''
        # Extract the size of the frame
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()

        # If the mouse left button is clicked close to the right edge allow horizontal resizing
        if  event.x > width-self.dragBandWidth : 
            self.resizeMode = self.HORIZONTAL        
        else:
            self.resizeMode = self.NONE


    def MonitorCursorPosition(self,event):        
        '''Check whether the cursor is close to the right or bottom edge of the frame.'''
        # Extract the size of the frame
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()

        # If the cursor is close to the right edge change cursor icon
        if  event.x > width-self.dragBandWidth : 
            self.config(cursor='sb_h_double_arrow')
        else:
            self.config(cursor='')

        # If horizontal resizing is allowed then resize frame with cursor
        if self.resizeMode == self.HORIZONTAL:
            self.config(width = event.x)
    

    def StopResize(self, event):
        '''Disable any resize mode and set the standard arrow as cursor.'''
        self.resizeMode = self.NONE
        self.config(cursor='')
 
# Root 
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Command Widget") 
root.geometry('600x400')
root.columnconfigure(0,weight = 0)
root.columnconfigure(1,weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)

# Resizable frame
resFrame = ResizableFrame(root, background = "blue",width = 100, height = 100)
resFrame.grid(row = 0, column=0,sticky = 'NWS')

# To remove notebook comment from here --> ======================
tab_notebook = ttk.Notebook(resFrame)
# Implement frames inside the notebook
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_notebook)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_notebook)
tab_notebook.add(tab1, text='Tab1',sticky='news')
tab_notebook.add(tab2, text='Tab2',sticky='news')
tab_notebook.pack(expand=True, fill="both",padx=(0,10))
# <-- to here ===================================================

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg= "red",width = 100, height = 100)
frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = 'NEWS')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding widgets into a frame using `.pack()` or `.grid()` will adjust the size of the frame by default. You can disable this by calling `.pack_propagate(0)` or `.grid_propagate(0)` on the frame:

```py
class ResizableFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pack_propagate(0)  # disable auto size adjustment when adding widgets using .pack()
        ...
```

However I would suggest to use `PanedWindow` widget instead of creating your own `ResizableFrame`:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

# Root
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Command Widget")
root.geometry('600x400')

resFrame = tk.PanedWindow(root, sashwidth=10, bg="blue", bd=0)
resFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

tab_notebook = ttk.Notebook(resFrame)
# Implement frames inside the notebook
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_notebook)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_notebook)
tab_notebook.add(tab1, text='Tab1',sticky='news')
tab_notebook.add(tab2, text='Tab2',sticky='news')
resFrame.add(tab_notebook)

frame1 = tk.Frame(resFrame, bg= "red")
resFrame.add(frame1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excellent  answer. It solved the problem of the custom resizable frame right away. And thank you very much for suggesting the PanedWindow.